# Purpose of sulphuric acid in archaic matchboxes

Tags: everyday-chemistry, combustion

The first attempts at instantaneous matchboxes usually included some sort of oxidizer, usually potassium chlorate and an initiating fuel (first sugar was used then they moved on to $\ce{Sb2S3}$ etc.) However the stick had to be dipped into a sulphuric acid solution and withdrawn for it to catch fire.

My question is:- How come the matchstick tip had to be dipped in $\ce{H2SO4}$ in order for it to catch fire? What was the acid doing? Was the active oxidant $\ce{HClO3}$?

Comment: Well, you gotta do *something* to set a match on fire - contact oxidiser with reducer. If one uses  a solution for that, I doubt you could think of a better one.

Comment: I don't think I get you, isn't sulphuric acid also an oxidant?

Comment: H2SO4 is not much of an oxidant, certainly not enough to start a fire by itself.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/4158/how-does-sulfuric-acid-catalyze-the-reaction-of-potassium-chlorate-and-sucrose?rq=1 It's the dehydrating nature of sulphuric acid i overlooked. I think this answers my question. Do i delete/close this?

Comment: Well, if you wanna get an automatic question ban, then go ahead and delete ;>

Comment: https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4398/9961

Comment: @GauravSaiMaddipati Instead of delete, you can self close the question by linking that question.

Comment: Good to know, however it seems my answer-hunting may have led to an incorrect conclusion as the answer below shows.

Answer (score 1):

You are right. $\ce{HClO3}$ is at the origin of the flame, and the dehydrating power of $\ce{H2SO4}$ has nothing to do here.

Anhydrous $\ce{H2SO4}$ reacts with $\ce{KClO3}$ to produce $\ce{HClO3}$ (and $\ce{KHSO4}$). When anhydrous, this $\ce{HClO3}$ is the active oxidant, but it is also an unstable compound, which is quickly and spontaneously decomposed. As soon as it is in contact with a reducing agent, like sugar of $\ce{Sb2S3}$, $\ce{HClO3}$ reacts strongly, producing $\ce{KCl}$ and oxygen, and these oxygen atoms create a flame with the sugar or $\ce{Sb2S3}$. In the $19$th century, the first matches were made with a mixture of molten $\ce{KClO3}$ and sugar (or another flammable substance) which were deposited on bits of wood. To get a flame, the matches had to be wetted with a tiny amount of concentrated sulfuric acid.

Today the acid has been suppressed. Matches contain only $\ce{KClO3}$ on wooden sticks. To start a fire, the matches are rubbed on a thin layer of red phosphorous $\ce{P_\mathrm{n}}$ : the friction heats a bit, enough to produce a flame, due to the reaction of $\ce{KClO3}$ on $\ce{P_\mathrm{n}}$ (and $\ce{P_\mathrm{n}}$ is probably partially transformed by friction into white phosphorous $\ce{P4}$, which is much more flammable).

Comment: Didn't we dip it into solution? How would it be anhydrous?

Comment: The last paragraph reminds me on Walter White (Breaking Bad) and the scene where he explains the modern design (link to a snippet on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a0KgYo96BpM)).  But how would one carry *safely* anhydrous $\ce{H2SO4}$ around?  Fuming $\ce{H2SO4}$ is the closest one to your description I came to use so far, and I'm glad it was stored in a solid glass bottle.

Comment: These old fire-kits certainly werent carried around, that's for sure.